# How to debug ng lint broken in angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

In my angular app, when I run the nglint I got this exception

```
    Cannot read property 'check-regex' of undefined

[error] TypeError: Cannot read property 'check-regex' of undefined

    at Rule.getRuleOptions (node_modules\tslint\lib\rules\maxLineLengthRule.js:51:72)
    at Rule.isEnabled (node_modules\tslint\lib\rules\maxLineLengthRule.js:39:26)
    at Object.loadRules (node_modules\tslint\lib\ruleLoader.js:48:22)
    at Linter.getEnabledRules (node_modules\tslint\lib\linter.js:232:29)
    at Linter.lint (node_modules\tslint\lib\linter.js:107:33)
    at _lint (node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tslint\index.js:146:20)
    at async _run (node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\tslint\index.js:60:29)
```

Do someone know how to debug this. Is there a way I can debug it like we do code (c#, javascript).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Debug in browser

Open Chrome browser(or install it first if you don't have it)

- Install [Node Inspector Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj?hl=en) extension
- Go to `node_modules\tslint\lib\rules\maxLineLengthRule.js:51:72` and add line before with `debugger;`
- Open console in your app and type

  ```
  node --inspect ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng lint
  ```

Chrome will open browser automatically  and you will be able to debug your issue just like you would do it in browser.

[image]

### Debug in VS Code

- open(or create first) `launch.json` file
- add the following configuration:

  ```
  {
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Debug lint",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\bin\\ng",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "args": ["lint"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal"
  }
  ```
- go to `node_modules\tslint\lib\rules\maxLineLengthRule.js:51:72` and put breakpoint there
- run Debug lint configuration

VS code should hit that breakpoint and you will be able to debug it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, when I put debugger and run the command, It doesn't open a chrome instance. I have chrome enterprise. Is there workaround for this, maybe we can debug it inside the vs code (if some security doesn't allow this)

Comment: Did you install and enable NIM extension?

Comment: I got it working, I just restart my chrome and it's look like working. thanks. I tried it from vs code now. earlier I was trying it from cmd.